# AT response clean-up

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial

I am trying to get the response from server using AT commands. This is my program

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 2; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 3; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266

// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESP8266.begin(115200); // Change this to the baudrate used by ESP8266
  delay(1000); // Let the module self-initialize
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sending an AT command...");
  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
  delay(3000);

  ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"192.168.50.1\",1234");
  delay(3000);
  
  while (ESP8266.available()){
     String res = ESP8266.readStringUntil('\t');
     Serial.println(res);
  }  

  
}
```

My server is just sending just one string as the output.

My console is getting this kind of output? Is there a way to clean this?

```
Sending an AT command...
AZi%PSՊj
C⸮j⸮L⸮AT+CIPSTART<0,"TCP","193.168.50.1",1234
0,CONNECT

OK
+IPD,0,1:10,CLOSDD

Sending an AT command...
```

I read [thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30760/inconsistent-response-at-command) and changed `SoftwareSerial.h` file. But still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you not use a library? WiFiEsp for example?

Comment: You can't use SoftwareSerial reliably at 115200 baud.

Comment: @Majenko Yes, I tested even for 9600

Comment: @Juraj can you given me an example? I had been looking for this days.

Comment: https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp